# SpriteKit Localization Hook-ups

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, localization

I've tried reading online tutorials on how to localize strings. I have a game that uses SpriteKit as an engine and has user-readable text in `.m` files.

My guess on localizing these strings is to swap where I have a readable string (`... .text = @"some string"`) with a call to `NSLocalizedString()`.

Say, I have a label that says "play" when the game starts up in English. In Spanish, it would say "jugar." In addition, I have an options menu, where in English, it says "options", and in Spanish, it says "opciones."

If I'm correct, I'd add two `.strings` files to the project: `en.string` and `es.string`.

In the code, I would add:

```
playLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"play", nil)

optionsLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"options", nil)
```

And, in the `en.strings` file, it would say,

```
"play" = "play";
"options" = "options";
```

In the `es.strings` file, it would say,

```
"play" = "jugar";
"options" = "opciones";
```

How would I make it so these `.strings` files were hooked up to the `GameScene.m` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and how to fix it. I read Ray Wanderlich's tutorial on this, available [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014).

How to fix this error, for those trying to figure this out in the future:

1. Create a new `strings` file named `Localizable.strings`.
2. Open the Utilities tab (the one on the right) if it's not already open.
3. Copy the text from `en.strings` and paste it into the `Localizable.strings` file.
4. Localize it into **every language you'll be localizing it into** (including Base) by clicking the button in the File Inspector labeled "Localize". It's hard to miss. (Note: You'll now notice a pull-down for a folder. Open it, and you'll find the `Localizable.strings` copied into every language you selected. However, it's not translated.)
5. Delete `en.strings`. It's no longer needed.
6. Copy and paste the text from `es.strings` into the `Localizable.strings`'s Spanish file, and delete `es.strings` afterwards. Repeat for every language you have it localized in.